# Need to dynamically create a data source for MySQL Connect/J connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have an application that needs to use connection pool when connection to the database.  Problem is, the application is designed to configure and change the connection settings on the fly.  I have written the following code that will allow me to dynamically create the data source and then use that to open the connections to the database.  However, this code was written for the DataDirect driver and I have used it to connect to Oracle and MS SQL.  Unfortunately, the DataDirect Mysql driver will only connect to the commercial version of mysql, not the free version.  So now I am attempting to accomplish the same task with connect/j from mysql.  I cannot find how to set the connection properties found in a external (static) datasource definition via method calls like for the DD driver.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
        BaseDataSource bds = (BaseDataSource)ds;

//  Populate the DataSource

        bds.setDescription("Driver Data Source");
        bds.setServerName(connectUrl);
        bds.setUser(userName);
        bds.setPassword(password);
        if ( spyAttr.length() > 0 ) bds.setSpyAttributes(spyAttr);

//  Create the PooledConnection DataSource.  Pass the data source created above
//  to the PooledConnection DataSource

        pds = new PooledConnectionDataSource();

        pds.setDescription("Pooled Data Source");
        pds.setDataSourceName("myDataSource", bds);
        pds.setPoolName("myPool");
        pds.setInitialPoolSize(nPoolSize);
        pds.setMinPoolSize(minPoolSize);
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        pds.setPropertyCycle(propCycle);
        pds.setMaxIdleTime(maxIdleTime);
        pds.setTracing(tracing);

//  Get connection

        pds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the MySQL Connector/J driver doesn't allow those parameters to be passed in with method calls so you will have to pass them in as parameters in the URL (jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=foo&password=bar).